# Unable to schedule Alarm using JobIntentService

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

I have been researching how to schedule an alarm targeting devices Oreo +.
My current approach is using `AlarmManager`, a Ringtone service and broadcast receiver. I got the alarm to ring and display notification but the notification and the alarm does not fire for Oreo + devices.

I learned that using `JobIntentService` is a good practice due to `Doze` and other background limitations. Currently, when using a `JobIntentService`, I get an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Am I doing this wrong? Do I really need to implement an `AsyncTask`?

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val alarmStatus: String = intent!!.getStringExtra("alarmStatus")
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, RingtoneService::class.java)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("alarmStatus", alarmStatus)
        //context!!.startService(serviceIntent)
        RingtoneService.enqueueWork(context, serviceIntent)
    }
}

class RingtoneService : JobIntentService() {
    // Enqueing work to do in this service.
    companion object {
        val SERVICE_JOB_ID = 1

        fun enqueueWork(context: Context?, work: Intent) {
            if (context != null) {
                enqueueWork(context, RingtoneService::class.java, RingtoneService.SERVICE_JOB_ID, work)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        onHandleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        //handling of notification goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to update your support libraries to the latest and greatest and put some number > 1 (to avoid having two different intent services with the same Id). If it doesn't help you might want to go deeper to this rabbit hole: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293
One of the suggested fixes there is to use a wrapper class around the JobIntentService:

```
package android.support.v4.app;

import android.content.Intent;

public abstract class FixedJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    @Override
    GenericWorkItem dequeueWork() {
        try {
            return new FixedGenericWorkItem(super.dequeueWork());
        } catch (SecurityException ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class FixedGenericWorkItem implements GenericWorkItem {
        final GenericWorkItem mGenericWorkItem;

        FixedGenericWorkItem(GenericWorkItem genericWorkItem) {
            mGenericWorkItem = genericWorkItem;
        }

        @Override
        public Intent getIntent() {
            if (mGenericWorkItem != null) {
                return mGenericWorkItem.getIntent();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void complete() {
            try {
                if (mGenericWorkItem != null) {
                    mGenericWorkItem.complete();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can try to use the new shiny WorkManager from the architecture components (may have issues if you have an app widget (the one for the android home screen) in your app).
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: what kind of issues will be with app widget using workmanager?